Action loops when an event is triggered
I created a task in the Windows Task Scheduler that starts when a test/322 event (event source/id) occurs in the "Application" log of the event viewer.
When I manually add a test/322 event in the Application log, the task launches but for some unknown reason it continually rewrites itself which means that the task is repeated continuously (until I deactivate it).
When I launch it manually it performs the task only once.
Do you have any idea why the task keeps rewriting itself and how to avoid this so that it only gets triggered once?
